# What will happen to a black hole if the Higgs field at the singularity is turned off?

Tags: black-holes, higgs, singularities

At high enough temperature the Higgs field VEV becomes zero (around $10^{15}~\rm K$ or so). Suppose the singularity reaches such a temperature, will all the mass vanish? What will happen then?

Note that a black hole appears cold to external observers but internally the temperature should be much higher. (At least that's what I read)

Comment: Mass of an infalling object becomes zero at the event horizon, so there is nothing inside a black hole. In fact, there is no such a place in our universe as "inside a black hole". A black hole is a region of a critically curved spacetime with a finite radius, but a zero volume.

Comment: Downvoters .. would appreciate if you justify.

Comment: @safesphere Perhaps, but could you give citations for those claims? Or at least write an actual answer that people can cast votes on...

Comment: @Jus12 Not my downvote, but from the question it seems that you are conflating two separate concepts: mass of an elementary particle and mass of a black hole.

Comment: @PM2Ring Here's one that I could find quickly: "The gravitational energy of the Schwarzschild black hole exists entirely outside its horizon and its value is the negative of the black hole mass." https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.05264.pdf This is not exactly what the OP asked, hence just a comment.

Comment: @safesphere That looks reasonable, and it's not controversial that the gravitational field of a BH is exterior to the EH. But that's not the same as saying the mass of infalling bodies becomes zero at the EH, although I agree that the body's contribution to the BH's gravitational field gets frozen when it crosses the EH.

Comment: @safesphere As for saying the interior of the BH doesn't exist in our universe, that's non-standard, although it's fair to say that there's a temporal discontinuity at the EH in Schwarzschild coordinates, and so it's sometimes described (e.g. by Penrose) that the BH interior is in the infinitely far future of a distant observer.

Answer (score 1):

No. The Higgs mechanism gives mass to the gauge bosons and fermions in the standard model. Mass can also come from other sources. The mass of a proton, for instance, is much greater than the sum of the masses of its constituents.

And keeping in mind that mass in relativity is essentially just total energy as measured in a particular reference frame, as long as energy is conserved, nothing can cause the mass of a black hole to vanish without anything being radiated away.

Comment: Higgs is only responsible for part of the mass at the current VEV. However, at zero VEV, quarks may not bind together, effectively making higher mass particles impossible.

Comment: Quarks bind together via gluon because they have color charge, which is unaffected by higgs vev

Comment: @Jus12 A black hole is bound by gravity, not the strong force. It's analogous to a proton, not the same thing. Even at zero VEV, quarks can most certainly not escape from inside the event horizon.

Comment: @mitcheil would quarks bind if they travel at the speed of light.

Comment: @Jus12 Why not? Gluons are massless and they're still bound in a proton.